# Snowflake execute immediate with using issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am just trying to test out some simple Snowflake in the web UI, and am seeing unexpected behavior.

This call to "execute immediate" without any variable works:

```
execute immediate 'select \'hi\' as textvalue, 5 as numbervalue'  ;
```

However, this call to "execute immediate" with a using variable throws "Syntax error: unexpected '5'."

```
execute immediate 'select \'hi\' as textvalue, ? as numbervalue' using (5) ;
```

What am I doing wrong that prevents this simple execution to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, it accepts a variable not a literal:

```
declare
   myparam number := 5;
begin
  execute immediate 'select \'hi\' as textvalue, ? as numbervalue' using (myparam) ;
end;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html#syntax

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<string_literal>'
    [ USING (bind_variable_1 [, bind_variable_2 ...] ) ] ;
```

bind_variable: **A bind variable** holds a value to be used in the cursor’s query definition

Comment: This requirement seems insane and really limits the versatility of the execute immediate functionality.